# ASP.NET/C# - Find entry in an array and get it's index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find a particular Textbox in an array of Textboxes, and return it's index.

This line finds the relevant control:

```
    TextBox tb1 = Array.Find(m_dynamicTextBoxes, element => element.ID == strFieldId);
```

I want to find it's index, ao that I can replace this control with a similar one. An error has been detected, so I plan to change the BorderColor to Red.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var index =  Array.FindIndex(m_dynamicTextBoxes, element => element.ID == strFieldId);
```

If you just want to change the `BackColor` then you can use your query and change the Color on your found TextBox

```
tb1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple LINQ extensions:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
  public static int? IndexOfOrNull<T>( this IEnumerable<T> list , Func<T,bool> isDesired  )
  {
    int  i       = 0     ;
    bool desired = false ;
    foreach ( T item in list )
    {
      desired = isDesired(item) ;
      if ( desired ) break ;
      ++i ;
    }
    return desired ? i : (int?)null ;
  }
  public static int IndexOf<T>( this IEnumerable<T> list , Func<T,bool> isDesired )
  {
    int? index = IndexOfOrNull( list , isDesired ) ;
    if ( !index.HasValue ) throw new InvalidOperationException() ;
    return index.Value ;
  }

}
```

Or you could write a similar extension to do the in-place replacement and return the replaced item:

```
public static T Replace<T>( this T[] list , Func<T,bool> isDesired , T replacement ) where T:class
{
  T replacedItem = null ;
  for ( int i = 0 ; replacedItem == null && i < list.Length ; ++i )
  {
    T item = list[i] ;
    bool desired = isDesired(item) ;
    if ( desired )
    {
      replacedItem = item ;
      list[i]      = replacement ;
    }
  }
  return replacedItem ; // the replaced item or null if no replacements were made.
}
```